# Scipy reporting different spearman correlation than pandas

Tags: pandas, scipy

```
print(n1)
print(n2)
print(type(n1), type(n2))
print(scipy.stats.spearmanr(n1, n2))
print(n1.corr(n2, method="spearman"))
0    2317.0
1    2293.0
2    1190.0
3     972.0
4    1391.0
Name: r6000, dtype: float64
0.0    2317.0
1.0    2293.0
3.0    1190.0
4.0     972.0
5.0    1391.0
Name: 6000, dtype: float64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
SpearmanrResult(correlation=0.9999999999999999, pvalue=1.4042654220543672e-24)
0.7999999999999999
```

The problem is that scipy was reporting a different correlation value than pandas.

Edit to add:

The issue is the indexes are off.  Pandas does automatic intrinsic data alignment, but scipy doesn't.  I've answered it below.

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes, that would help me as well!  I'll try to do some more debugging and see if I can answer this question myself.

Comment: See also: [Differences between dataframe spearman correlation using pandas and scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434285/differences-between-dataframe-spearman-correlation-using-pandas-and-scipy)

Comment: See my answer below.  Seems like it should have just failed, but I'm sure there's a reason why it didn't.   Something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a copy and called reset_index() on the series before correlating them.  That fixed it.

The issue is intrinsic automatic data alignment in pandas based on the indexes.

scipy library doesn't do automatic data alignment, likely just converts it to a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas does't have a function that calculates p-values, so it is better to use SciPy to calculate correlation since it will give you both p-value and correlation coefficient. The other alternative is to calculate the p-value yourself....using Scipy. Note one thing: If you are calculating the correlation of a sample of your data using pandas, the risk is that the correlations change if you change your sample is high. This is why you need the p-value.

Comment: I wasn't looking at the pvalue, just the correlation.  The columns should be equal